# Python Pandas Upsampling - Complex Issue Preserving Some np.Nans

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
              A        B

2010-01-01    6.5     3.2
2010-02-01    7.2     np.Nan
2010-03-01    8.1     np.Nan
2010-04-01    4.3     5.6
2010-05-01    3.7     6.1
```

I want to upsample to days and forward fill values.  But in the case of `df['B']`  I want the forward fill to *stop* where `np.Nan` values start.  I'm looking for the following:

```
               A       B
2010-01-01    6.5     3.2
2010-01-02    6.5     3.2
 ....
2010-01-31    6.5     3.2
2010-02-01    7.2     np.Nan
2010-02-02    7.2     np.Nan
 ....   
2010-02-28    7.2     np.Nan
2010-03-01    8.1     np.Nan
2010-03-02    8.1     np.Nan
 ....
2010-03-31    8.1     np.Nan
2010-04-01    4.3     5.6
2010-04-02    4.3     5.6
 ....
2010-04-30    4.3     5.6
2010-05-01    3.7     6.1
2010-05-02    3.7     6.1
 ....
2010-05-31    3.7     6.1
```

If I apply the following code:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].resample('D').ffill()
df['B'] = df['B'].resample('D').ffill()
```

My results look like this:

```
               A       B
2010-01-01    6.5     3.2
2010-01-02    6.5     3.2
 ....
2010-01-31    6.5     3.2
2010-02-01    7.2     3.2
2010-02-02    7.2     3.2
 ....   
2010-02-28    7.2     3.2
2010-03-01    8.1     3.2
2010-03-02    8.1     3.2
 ....
2010-03-31    8.1     3.2
2010-04-01    4.3     5.6
2010-04-02    4.3     5.6
 ....
2010-04-30    4.3     5.6
2010-05-01    3.7     6.1
2010-05-02    3.7     6.1
 ....
2010-05-31    3.7     6.1
```

`df['B']` is filled with the `3.2` value from `2010-01-01` up through `2010-03-31` instead of "stopping' at  `2010-01-31` and preserving the `np.Nan` from `2010-02-01` through `2010-03-31`.

I know I can do this using a very messy iterative process.  But is there an easier way to do this i'm not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: Will fillna work? re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136663/using-pandas-to-fill-gaps-only-and-not-nans-on-the-ends

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `nan` to another value , waiting for `replace` back after we `resample`

```
df=df.fillna('replaceNAN')
s=df.resample('D').ffill().replace('replaceNAN',np.nan)
s.loc[s.isnull().any(1)]
Out[456]: 
              A    B
2010-02-01  7.2  NaN
2010-02-02  7.2  NaN
2010-02-03  7.2  NaN
2010-02-04  7.2  NaN
2010-02-05  7.2  NaN
2010-02-06  7.2  NaN
2010-02-07  7.2  NaN
2010-02-08  7.2  NaN
2010-02-09  7.2  NaN
2010-02-10  7.2  NaN
2010-02-11  7.2  NaN
2010-02-12  7.2  NaN
2010-02-13  7.2  NaN
2010-02-14  7.2  NaN
2010-02-15  7.2  NaN
2010-02-16  7.2  NaN
2010-02-17  7.2  NaN
2010-02-18  7.2  NaN
2010-02-19  7.2  NaN
2010-02-20  7.2  NaN
2010-02-21  7.2  NaN
2010-02-22  7.2  NaN
2010-02-23  7.2  NaN
2010-02-24  7.2  NaN
2010-02-25  7.2  NaN
2010-02-26  7.2  NaN
2010-02-27  7.2  NaN
2010-02-28  7.2  NaN
2010-03-01  8.1  NaN
2010-03-02  8.1  NaN
2010-03-03  8.1  NaN
2010-03-04  8.1  NaN
2010-03-05  8.1  NaN
2010-03-06  8.1  NaN
2010-03-07  8.1  NaN
2010-03-08  8.1  NaN
2010-03-09  8.1  NaN
2010-03-10  8.1  NaN
2010-03-11  8.1  NaN
2010-03-12  8.1  NaN
2010-03-13  8.1  NaN
2010-03-14  8.1  NaN
2010-03-15  8.1  NaN
2010-03-16  8.1  NaN
2010-03-17  8.1  NaN
2010-03-18  8.1  NaN
2010-03-19  8.1  NaN
2010-03-20  8.1  NaN
2010-03-21  8.1  NaN
2010-03-22  8.1  NaN
2010-03-23  8.1  NaN
2010-03-24  8.1  NaN
2010-03-25  8.1  NaN
2010-03-26  8.1  NaN
2010-03-27  8.1  NaN
2010-03-28  8.1  NaN
2010-03-29  8.1  NaN
2010-03-30  8.1  NaN
2010-03-31  8.1  NaN
```